# shape of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, shapes

Have an incoming numpy array which can be 1-d or 2-d. I'm trying to find the number of row using `shape` property. My calculation `x.shape[0]` is failing as for 1-d array, it isn't giving (1,6). Any suggestion how to calculate `# of row` independent of whether the array is 1-d or 2-d?

**2-d array:**

```
>>> x4
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> x4.shape
(2, 3)
>>> row, col = x4.shape
```

**1-d array**

```
>>> x3
array([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
>>> x3.shape
(6,)
```

Comment: Depending on how you look at it, a 1d array doesn't have rows (or columns) - just elements.  `row` and `column` are convenient labels for 2d arrays, but aren't formally part of the `numpy` documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the last dimension's size instead with `-1`:

```
>>> x3.shape[-1]
6

>>> x4.shape[-1]
3
```

However, to get the *broadcasted* shape for 2D and 1D arrays alike, you might want to unpack the shape and use `1` as the default number of rows:

```
>>> *r, c = x3.shape
>>> ((r or [1])[0], c)
(1, 6)

>>> *r, c = x4.shape
>>> ((r or [1])[0], c)
(2, 3)
```

Which means:

- if the array is **1D**, `r` is an empty *list* `[]`, which is [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false), so you end up with `(r or [1])[0]` equal to `[1][0]`, *i.e.* `1`.
- if the array is **2D**, `r` is a *list* containing the number of rows as its first element, a non-empty *list* is truthy,  so you end up with `r[0]`.

See [*extending iterable unpacking*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for more on this usage of the asterisk ***** in Python.

---

An alternative way is to prepend `1` to the shape straight away. Then, extract the last two elements of that *tuple*. This will return the correct row and column numbers, regardless if it's a 1D- or 2D-array:

```
>>> ((1,) + x3.shape)[-2:]
(1, 6)

>>> ((1,) + x4.shape)[-2:]
(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the last value of the shape?

```
x1 = np.ones(10)
x1.shape([-1])

x2 = np.ones((10,6))
x2.shape([-1])
```

Comment: I want the `row number`. I can make a conditional statement but that doesn't look elegant.

Comment: Yes, but what do you call a row in a 1-d array? And a row number?

Answer (score 0):

YOu could use `atleast_2d` to add a leading dimension:

```
In [56]: np.atleast_2d(np.arange(3))
Out[56]: array([[0, 1, 2]])
In [57]: _.shape
Out[57]: (1, 3)
In [58]: np.atleast_2d(np.ones((2,3)))
Out[58]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
In [59]: _.shape
Out[59]: (2, 3)
```

But look at it's code - it hides a dimension test.

```
    elif ary.ndim == 1:
        result = ary[_nx.newaxis, :]
```